# Sharepoint Designer Workflow - how to link a variable to person information.

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

Hmm i cant post a pick so I will try to describe.

So I am trying to share the Person or group information stored in the Reviewer field of the Reviewer list.

In my main List I have a business area that if it is "sales" should look up the reviewer (1 to 1 rel) and store his details in a variable. But the variables can only be String int etc, so I am wondering how best to reference this.

If I use a lookup on the Reviewer Field in Reviewers I get the Persons options
{
String 
Display Name
Login Name
Email Address
}

But I want to collect data from the Person also later ??

can this be done ???

p.s. I need 2 more rep points to be able to post a photo :(

Answer (score 1):

Got around it by using the ID of the row and using that ID to look up the person on that row and return a String. On the dropdown as to what value to return email address was an option that I was trying to use but this didnt work and returning the Person as a strin